# How does Android verifies deep links with Digital Asset Links at server side

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to enable deep linking for my Android app. Based on my understanding of description given at [Handling App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) following changes are required to enable deep linking for an Android app:

1. Publish Digital Asset Links on server side.
2. Add intent filter for deep linking support.
3. Set autoVerify true in the above intent filter if we don't want to see app suggestions.

I have following questions which remain unanswered:

- How does Android verify deep links with Digital Asset Links published at server?
- Does this verification require requesting https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json every time user clicks a linked declared in intent filter?
- Does Android download the assetlinks.json file at the time of app installation and all further verification is done locally without hitting the server?

I will appreciate any help in understanding the verification process.

Disclaimer: I have just started Android programming.

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. When a a user installs the app, Android sees the intent filter and
   checks for the presence of the statement list at the specified site;
   if present, Android checks whether that file includes a statement
   granting link handling to the app, and verifies the app against the
   statement by certificate hash. If everything checks out, Android
   will then forward any https://www.example.com intents to the
   example.com app.
2. When a auser clicks a link to https://www.example.com/puppies on
   their device.  Android forwards the intent to the example.com app.
3. The verification is done only at the time of Installation

You can learn more here:   https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started

Comment: Can I ask you something more? When I see this [document](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/consuming), I can imagine the flow of the request for the statement would be like `app(client)` → `google API` → `your server`, which I simply tell it's server-side request. But when I check [this](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator), I can imagine the flow would be like `app(client)` → `your server`, which I simply tell it's client-side request. Which one is right?